# Azure AD B2C automatic logout after session timeout

Tags: blazor-webassembly, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have a SPA on Blazor that is already migrated to B2C and login/logout functionality works fine.

I also created and run a SignUp_SignIn custom policy according to [this MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) and everything seems to work fine.
After the session is expired, if I open a new browser tab, I am prompted to login again.

However, if I open my application, successfully log in into it via B2C, wait a configured amount of time and after the session time is expired it does not automatically logs me out and redirects to the login page.

So, **the question is**: Should automatic logout after session expiry be implemented on the application side or should I add any additional configuration to my custom policy?

Comment: Could not find the specific answer to your question, but [these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-azure-active-directory-b2c?view=aspnetcore-7.0) do provide more specific info on B2C with Blazor Apps that you may find helpful

Comment: What did you end up doing? I asked this exact question a little while ago to no avail either.